# Where is save to data base woocommerce after buy product(checkout page)?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Where is the saving in the database a plug-in to worldpress woocommerce after the purchase of the product (checkout page)?
Where is the saving in the database when confirming the order in woocommerce?
I need to substitute the code of my discount, so that it reduces the final result, in the View I know how to change, but when is the order confirmation, where do I need to add my code?
I can not find a file where POST sends my form, there is for example action = "site.loc / checkout", how do I know where it sends POST? I can not understand how routing works in wordpresse ..
Where can I look with the help of the debugger.
Tell me please.

Comment: I found example.
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'send_data_to_another_table');
but the price for all goods is not transferred by fasting, where is the saving in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Save to DB in this file
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php